# Rails 4 and action caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading a Rails app 3 to 4 that relays heavily on action_caching due to traffic. `caches_action` has been moved out from Rails 4 in favour or fragment caching and russian doll.

My question is what is the current solution to action cache? I see the current fragment caching is at least one way of magnitude slower since it is not caching anymore every action logic. My app went from below 200ms to over 2000ms without using `caches_action` even if I'm using cache on the views.

I been searching but haven't found any article or documentation that digs deeper into this. Maybe i'm missing something obvious.

What is the current Rails 4 approach to action caching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe for people in your situation (code relying on action caching) the best solution is to use the [actionpack-action_caching gem](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching).

```
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'

caches_action :index, :show # should work again
```

Comment: In what scenario most part of the logic code does not rely on the action?

Comment: @Martin sry I meant to say existing code relying on action caching.

Comment: And what would be the long term solution to this? Cause this gem is just for easing the transition through rails 4, but it no longer works on rails 5.